# How to delare an iterator for a set of Binary trees

Tags: c++

I keep on getting issues when i try to compile this code. I think the origin of the problem is the declaration of the iterator in the set and so the erase operations are giving problems as a consequence.
The compilation error is the following:

the compiler gives this message:

```
Treecode.cc: In member function ‘void Treecode::recalcular_treecode()’:
Treecode.cc:35:24: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >}’ and ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >}’)
     it = cjt_arb.begin();
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/debug/set:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/set:66,
                 from Treecode.hh:10,
                 from Treecode.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/safe_iterator.h:199:7: note: candidate: __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>& __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>::operator=(const __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>&) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Sequence = std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >]
       operator=(const _Safe_iterator& __x) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/safe_iterator.h:199:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >}’ to ‘const __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >&’
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/safe_iterator.h:231:7: note: candidate: __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>& __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>::operator=(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>&&) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; _Sequence = std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >]
       operator=(_Safe_iterator&& __x) noexcept
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/safe_iterator.h:231:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >}’ to ‘__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >&&’
Treecode.cc:42:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::erase(std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator&)’
         it = cjt_arb.erase(it);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/debug/set:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/set:66,
                 from Treecode.hh:10,
                 from Treecode.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:346:7: note: candidate: std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::erase(std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator) [with _Key = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = Treecode::ordena; _Allocator = std::allocator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >]
       erase(const_iterator __position)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:346:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >}’ to ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >}’
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:363:7: note: candidate: std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::size_type std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::erase(const key_type&) [with _Key = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = Treecode::ordena; _Allocator = std::allocator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::key_type = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >]
       erase(const key_type& __x)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:363:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >}’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >&}’
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:378:7: note: candidate: std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::erase(std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator, std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator) [with _Key = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = Treecode::ordena; _Allocator = std::allocator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >]
       erase(const_iterator __first, const_iterator __last)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:378:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
Treecode.cc:45:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::erase(std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator&)’
         it = cjt_arb.erase(it);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/debug/set:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/set:66,
                 from Treecode.hh:10,
                 from Treecode.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:346:7: note: candidate: std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::erase(std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator) [with _Key = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = Treecode::ordena; _Allocator = std::allocator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >]
       erase(const_iterator __position)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:346:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >}’ to ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >}’
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:363:7: note: candidate: std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::size_type std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::erase(const key_type&) [with _Key = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = Treecode::ordena; _Allocator = std::allocator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::key_type = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >]
       erase(const key_type& __x)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:363:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > > >}’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >&}’
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:378:7: note: candidate: std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::erase(std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator, std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator) [with _Key = BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = Treecode::ordena; _Allocator = std::allocator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >; std::__debug::set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>::const_iterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >, std::__debug::set<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >; typename std::__cxx1998::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<BinTree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >]
       erase(const_iterator __first, const_iterator __last)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/set.h:378:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

I've tried dereferencing the declaration doing it = cjt_arb.begin() in the next line but it doesn't work.

```
#include "Treecode.hh"
using namespace std;



void Treecode::recalcular_treecode() {

    set<BinTree<pair<string,int>>>::iterator it = cjt_arb.begin(); // Problem probably here
    if (cjt_arb.size() == 1) {tree = *it;}
    else {
        pair <string, int> a;
        pair <string, int> b;
        BinTree <pair <string,int> > left = *it;
        a = left.value();
        it = cjt_arb.erase(it);
        BinTree <pair <string,int> > right = *it;
        b = right.value();
        it = cjt_arb.erase(it);
        pair <string, int> node;
        if (a.first <b.first) {node.first = a.first + b.first;}
        else {node.first = b.first + a.first;}
        node.second = a.second + b.second;
        BinTree<pair<string,int>> unio(node,left, right);
        cjt_arb.insert(unio);
        recalcular_treecode();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I keep on getting issues when i try to compile this code."_  care to share these with us so we don't have to guess.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful error description. "Doesn't compile because of error message [...]" or "Crashes at runtime because `*it` points to invalid memory" or similar would be much more helpful.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the type of `it` with `auto`?

Comment: what is `cjt_arb` ? Please [mcve]

Comment: that worked, is it safe?

Comment: Using `auto` for type deduction is safe as in that it figures out the correct type of `cjt_arb.begin()` automatically. It is unsafe in the sense of that the compiler has no idea if that is what you wanted. Maybe you meant `cjt_arb` to be `const`, maybe not. The compiler can't tell and neither can we.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already figured out, the compiler is complaining about `it = cjt_arb.begin();` not compiling. It tries to tell you why:

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__debug::set, int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator, int> > >, std::__debug::set, int> > > >}’ and ‘std::__debug::set, int> >, Treecode::ordena>::iterator {aka __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator, int> > >, std::__debug::set, int> >, Treecode::ordena> >}’)
>        it = cjt_arb.begin();

What it is trying to say is

> Error: No valid `operator=` to assign a `set<BinTree<pair<string,int>>>::const_iterator` to a `set<BinTree<pair<string,int>>>::iterator` because that would drop the `const`ness.

Your `cjt_arb` seems to be `const`, so you can't modify it, so you cannot get a non-`const` iterator to it. Replace `set<BinTree<pair<string,int>>>::iterator` with `set<BinTree<pair<string,int>>>::const_iterator` or remove the `const` from `cjt_arb` and it should compile.